# Why Django admin shows different kind of UI interface?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, localhost

I am new to django, when i created a project and goes to 'url/admin'. It shows the default django admin UI. But now, when i navigate to 'url/admin'. It shows different UI of admin login than default one.

I attached the screenshot of it, how it is looking. How to make this screen to look as default one of django admin screen?

Kindly see the url too in screenshot. Why after 'url/admin' more string shown.

[image: django admin]

[image: django admin dashboard]

My settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for common project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.8.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))



# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '***************************************************'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['common-module.herokuapp.com','127.0.0.1']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'user'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'common.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'common.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'common',
        'USER':'postgres',
        'PASSWORD':'****',
        'HOST':'localhost'
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Comment: looks like you have not setup `static` url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your settings.py set `DEBUG = True`

Comment: Yes it worked, that thing make it default one.

I have one more question, if i made DEBUG = True then during deployment i have to make this DEBUG = False, then how to handle this situation at that time. I also updated the question and also attach the settings.py

Comment: @Umair in deployment you need to run **collectstatic**, check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/deployment/).

Answer (score 0):

If Debug is True and still not visible proper UI then you should refresh page using ignoring cached content.
Command : CTRL+Shift+R